# $modal not loading on $stateChangeStart,instead the $stateChangeStart is getting triggered infinitely

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-router, infinite-loop

I am trying to throw a login modal when a user tries to change his state to **app**.

A service loginService is called when the state changes to **app**. The code is going in to the service and goes in to an infinite loop from stateChange.(The alerts 'in run' and 'in service' run infinitely) after stopping the alerts manually the modal is also thrown infinitely.

the stateChange is happening again and again is what i feel.

Thanks in advance to anybody who helps.
I am quite new to angularjs and i have been simply trying out these things.
Link to the plunk is:http://plnkr.co/edit/7b16Df1d8ubDBuu2qXg3

```
 app.run(function($state,$rootScope,loginService){
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event,toState,toParams){
 if(toState.name==='app'){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('in run');
  if(loginService.openModal()){
    $state.go(toState.name);
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    $state.go('welcome');
  }


}
});
});
 app.factory('loginService',['$modal',function($modal){
 return{
      openModal:function(){
         alert("in service");
         var modalLoginInstance=$modal.open({
         // template:alert('in modal instance'),
         templateUrl:'loginModalTemplate.html',
         controller:'modalInstanceCTRL'
    });
   return modalLoginInstance.result.then(function(){alert('in success');return true},function(){alert('in failure');return false});
}
};
}]);
```

Comment: I suggest you try to reduce this down to the smallest example that recreates these symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Oops! I was able to find out the mistake i had added an extra **return** at the end of modalinstance.

```
 return modalLoginInstance.result.then(function(){alert('in success');return true},function(){alert('in failure');return false});}
```

the first return here needs to be removed.

the correct one is

```
modalLoginInstance.result.then(function(){alert('in success');return true},function(){alert('in failure');return false});}
```